# Connecting points on a graph within nested groups of data with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm having a problem working out how to draw lines between points on a `ggplot` that are in a nested structure.

What I have is a set of data that is broken down by 3 different nested groups. 
Which are then plotted, the first group is used with facet to pair the subgroups (`Mutation`), the second group then splits the data into the initial experiment (`HiSeq`) and the replication experiment (`MiSeq`), while the third group (`Grouping`) colors and shapes the points by the sample type they are from.

Where I have gotten stuck though is I'd like to link the 2 points (HiSeq/Miseq) within an pair (mutation) via a line to make it easy to workout which two are linked. I've made a mock up which can be seen:

[image: here, which shows roughly what I want to try and do]
However I'm unable to work out how to do this across the two groups (HiSeq/Miseq) while staying within the top level group (Mutation).

Does any one have a solution to this? A fragment of the data and the code I'm using to build the current graph can be seen below. It may end up being to messy to be presentable but it would be useful to solve.

```
ggplot(test,aes(y=AR,x=Type,fill=Grouping,colour=Grouping,shape=Grouping)) + 
    geom_point(binaxis='y',stackdir='center',position=position_dodge(width = 0.2),size=7) + 
    facet_wrap(~ Mutation,nrow=1) + 
    xlab("") + 
    ylab("Allelic Ratio") + 
    theme_minimal(base_size=20)
```

**example data**:

```
structure(list(Mutation = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("chr1:51910329", 
"chr1:72951069"), class = "factor"), Type = structure(c(1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L), .Label = c("HiSeq", "MiSeq"), class = "factor"), Grouping = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Offspring (M)", "Offspring (P)", "Proband"
), class = "factor"), Name = c(288458773L, 288458773L, 423125012L, 
423125012L, 344991226L, 344991226L, 422977809L, 422977809L, 420753074L, 
420753074L, 351142406L, 351142406L, 422743921L, 422743921L, 425596544L, 
425596544L, 422595517L, 422595517L, 477342393L, 477342393L, 288458773L, 
288458773L, 423125012L, 423125012L, 344991226L, 344991226L, 422977809L, 
422977809L, 420753074L, 420753074L, 351142406L, 351142406L, 477342393L, 
477342393L, 480773638L, 480773638L), AR = c(0.38, 0.3, 0, 0, 
0.375, 0.545, 0.41, 0.388, 0.35, 0.42, 0, 0, NA, 0.59, NA, 0, 
0, 0.05, 0, 0, 0.1875, 0.078379734, 0.4, 0.505582473, 0, 0.002394493, 
0, 0.002023547, 0, 0.001600569, 0.6, 0.510240797, 0.6, 0.490997813, 
0, 0.001785424)), .Names = c("Mutation", "Type", "Grouping", 
"Name", "AR"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -36L))
```

Comment: Data has been provided as output of dput() now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this may be what you want -- look into `geom_line` and understanding its `group` aesthetic:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Type, y = AR, fill = Grouping, color = Grouping, shape = Grouping)) +
  geom_point(size = 5) +
  geom_line(aes(group =  Name)) +
  facet_wrap(~ Mutation)
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: Yes that's it exactly, I'd not realised it was possible to use additional groups like the name in the different geom.